# scrapy how to scrape random text or without class and id

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to scrape text, 1,910,400 and the start date and end date as in picture below, but it is just a random text without div class or id. How do I scrape it using the specific format?

The coding format I am currently using:

[image]

The html code tag:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this XPath (find `div` that contains `strong` that value is `Max ERC Funding` and next get following text node):

```
quote.xpath('.//div[strong[.="Max ERC Funding"]]/following-sibling::text()[1]').get()
```

Comment: do u know why it shows in terminal output but wont show in excel json file when i insert -o .csv ?